# My Minecraft.jar file won't launch

Tags: java, minecraft, openjdk

I have downloaded the Minecraft.jar file, and I have made sure to set in properties to allow it to be executed as a program, and I have java installed.
But when I run it by `java -jar Minecraft.jar`, it all goes well until: `Loaded 1 profile(s); selected '(Default)'`, there isn't an error, but nothing happens, when I tried to close the terminal, it says the process is still running, I left it for a few hours, and when I came back, it was still at that. If I open it with OpenJDK 8 Java runtime, the same happens, without the output. I'm running version 16.04, codename xenial. If you need anymore information please say.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give a full paste of the terminal, including the command?

Comment: Loaded 1 profile(s); selected '(Default)' it means that the game has launched. In my case it is the last line in the console after which the game starts up, and that line only changes when you exit the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I had my computer connected to a TV screen, and the launcher window was opening in the computer screen (I couldn't see it because I'd turned down the brightness to 0 on the computer screen, I hadn't realized it worked like that)